# get all the descendants Elements(controls) of VBox(container) in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, containers, vbox

can we get all the elements and all the **descendants of those elements** in a

> VBox

?
lets say i have Vobx, in which a grid is added.. and in grid there are many texinput controls..  i want to access all the descendants which are

> Grid,GridRow,GridItem,TextInput

.. how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to write a recursive function that traverses the hierarchy of components. There is no built-in method to access children below the first level of a container.

Something like:

```
function traceDisplayObject(object:DisplayObject):void {
  trace("Object: " + object);

  if (object is Container) {
    var container:Container = Container(object);
    var numChildren:uint = container.numChildren;

    for (var i:uint = 0; i<numChildren; i++) {
      traceDisplayObject(container.getChildAt(i));
    }
  }
}

traceDisplayObject(myVBox);
```

Comment: if (object is Container)... object could be grid containing textinput ?

Comment: When you traverse the object graph and come to the GridItem, then you'll have the TextInput as one of its children.